# $PATH is not working

Tags: bash, path

The following file worked yesterday, but today it isn't working any more.

Could be caused by either the `apt-get upgrade` or `autoremove` that I performed.

For some reason $PATH isn't working, I have no idea why not.

```
$ cat GW
#!/bin/bash
PATH="/media/Data/Wine/WineVersions/1.3.24/bin:$PATH"
export WINEPREFIX="/media/Data/Wine/WinePrefixes/GW"
export WINEDEBUG="-all"
cd "/media/Data/Wine/WinePrefixes/GW/drive_c/Program Files/Guild Wars"
wine Gw.exe

$ ./GW
./GW: line 6: /media/Data/Wine/WineVersions/1.3.24/bin/wine: No such
file or directory

$ ls /media/Data/Wine/WineVersions/1.3.24/bin/wine
/media/Data/Wine/WineVersions/1.3.24/bin/wine
```

I also tried `export PATH="blablabla"` but that didn't work either.

Edit: Requested info

```
$ file /media/Data/Wine/WinePrefixes/GW/drive_c/Program\ Files/Guild\ Wars/Gw.exe
/media/Data/Wine/WinePrefixes/GW/drive_c/Program Files/Guild Wars/Gw.exe: PE32 executable for MS Windows (GUI) Intel 80386 32-bit

# Not a symlink
$ ls -l /media/Data/Wine/WineVersions/1.3.24/bin/wine gives -rwxr-xr-x 1 j j 7244
2011-08-11 17:18 /media/Data/Wine/WineVersions/1.3.24/bin/wine
```

Comment: try `wine ./Gw.exe`. Also post `file '/media/Data/Wine/WinePrefixes/GW/drive_c/Program Files/Guild Wars/Gw.exe'`

Comment: That is a binary file, and as the error message shows the problem is in the wine command, not the other binary

Comment: nonetheless: `$ file /media/Data/Wine/WinePrefixes/GW/drive_c/Program\ Files/Guild\ Wars/Gw.exe` `/media/Data/Wine/WinePrefixes/GW/drive_c/Program Files/Guild Wars/Gw.exe: PE32 executable for MS Windows (GUI) Intel 80386 32-bit`

Comment: If PATH was not working then how would the shell know to look in '/media/Data/Wine/WineVersions/1.3.24/bin' to find it? Porblem is not with PATH

Comment: Then I have no idea whatsoever as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I autoremoved a bunch of libraries that wine required, I hadn't installed the standard wine package, instead using individual builds.

`ia32-libs` allowed the executable to start, I am cross-referencing the contents of `/var/log/apt/history.log` with `apt-cache showpkg wine1.2` to find what I need to install.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `/media/Data/Wine/WineVersions/1.3.24/bin/wine` exists, but is an orphaned symlink or otherwise broken.

Comment: `$ ls -l /media/Data/Wine/WineVersions/1.3.24/bin/wine` gives `-rwxr-xr-x 1 j j 7244 2011-08-11 17:18 /media/Data/Wine/WineVersions/1.3.24/bin/wine`

Comment: 7244 bytes for `wine`: it looks like a bash script. Try to `export PATH`.

Comment: Tried that, same result, and I posted output of `file` up top

Comment: `file` output for `wine` could be helpful too. Does its first line contain a shebang with a path to a nonexistent or broken binary? Concur with comments that `PATH` is not your problem.